Другие устройства не видят docker контейнеры развёрнутые на ПК
Мне необходимо развернуть докер на хостинге для приложения-клиента на телефоне, но пока сделал локально. По адресу localhost:8080 на машине возвращается json как мне и необходимо, но при попытке подключиться с телефона по ip моей машины + ":8080" контейнеры не видно, будто бы у них нет выхода во внешнюю сеть или по какой-то другой причине.
docker file:

FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 AS build


WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080


COPY target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .



CMD ["java", "-jar", "demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]


docker-compose:
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    container_name: my-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/my_db
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: pass
      IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH: /app/images/ # Путь к папке для картинок
    volumes:
      - ./images:/app/images # Монтируем локальную папку images в контейнер
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass

    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-d", "my_db" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3






Вполне может не быть выхода на внешнюю сеть, убедитесь в работоспособности сети прежде чем разбираться с докером

Ну наверняка на хостинге все "лишние" порты наружу по умолчанию закрыты, нужно читать доки хостинга и открывать порты, которые вы хотите выставить наружу.

Во время разворачивания на локальной машине, из-за того что я использую интернет который даёт сеть университета, мне необходимо подключаться по ip адресу внутри этой сети, а не по внешнему айпи как я пытался сделать до этого.
С подключением к контейнеру развёрнутому на хостинге никаких проблем обнаружено не было
